# Ruby Array of Hashes; keep only first element containing a certain key=>value pair

Tags: ruby, arrays, dictionary

Let's say I have the following array of hashes in Ruby:

```
a = [{:id => 1, :species =>"Homo sapiens"},
     {:id => 2, :species =>"Canis lupus"},
     {:id => 3, :species =>"Bos taurus"},
     {:id => 4, :species =>"Homo sapiens"},
     {:id => 5, :species =>"Pan troglodytes"},
     {:id => 6, :species =>"Bos taurus"}]
```

**What is the most idiomatic and concise way to only keep the first element containing each `:species` key (i.e., to discard any elements that repeat the species name)?** For the example above, the desired result would look like this:

```
b = [{:id => 1, :species =>"Homo sapiens"},
     {:id => 2, :species =>"Canis lupus"},
     {:id => 3, :species =>"Bos taurus"},
     {:id => 5, :species =>"Pan troglodytes"}]
```

I can accomplish this by first reading all species into a second array, removing duplicates with `uniq!`, and then iterating through the original array for the first element containing each species represented in the second array, but this seems very un-Ruby-like, and looks rather ugly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to use [`Array#uniq`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-uniq) :-

```
a = [{:id => 1, :species =>"Homo sapiens"},
     {:id => 2, :species =>"Canis lupus"},
     {:id => 3, :species =>"Bos taurus"},
     {:id => 4, :species =>"Homo sapiens"},
     {:id => 5, :species =>"Pan troglodytes"},
     {:id => 6, :species =>"Bos taurus"}]

a.uniq { |h| h[:species] }
# => [{:id=>1, :species=>"Homo sapiens"},
#     {:id=>2, :species=>"Canis lupus"},
#     {:id=>3, :species=>"Bos taurus"},
#     {:id=>5, :species=>"Pan troglodytes"}]
```

Comment: Great - this is perfect. Both concise and legible. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect, perfetto, parfait, perfekt, perfecto, 完ぺき, 完美, 완전한 !